# Get lat/lng center of country, state or district

Tags: openstreetmap

Given is a DB full of parent/child relationships of political district geo data/names:

- Country
- State
- District

Now I'm querying for that data, building a string like `germany,bavaria,ebersberg` and then I try to fetch the lat/lng center of that district via the [*Nominatim* API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) (part of OpenStreetMaps).

Example String:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=xml&polygon=0&addressdetails=0&q=germany,bavaria,ebersberg
```

Problem is, that I get back a bunch of POIs with lat/lng instead exact geographical data. This often results in having exact the half of that district displayed as the first POI could be close to that districts border.

Does anyone know of a way to get the lat/lng of the center or how to center a OSM map? OR does anyone know of an alternate API that can achieve this and tell how it works/make an example?

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps and google-maps-api-3?  Are you using a Google Map?  The Google Maps API v3 Geoocoder, returns bounds of for the geographic region and a suggested viewport, but per the Terms of Use, those results need to be displayed on a Google Map.

Comment: @geocodezip Was a mistake as I have another part of the app where the Google Maps API is in use.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a way to get the lat/lng of the center or how to center a OSM map?

When you get a bunch (list, set) of points of interest with latitudes and longitudes, you have a feature, not a problem.

You iterate through the POI, building a bounding rectangle that includes all of the POI.  In other words, you find the minimum latitude, minimum longitude, maximum latitude, and maximum longitude.

You find the center of the rectangle by the formula

```
(maximum + minimum) / 2
```

The bounding area should be small enough that you're not going to incur much error working with latitude and longitude.

Otherwise, you can calculate the distance between the minimum latitude, longitude and the maximum latitude, longitude.  The center is half the distance from the minimum latitude, longitude.  Convert that center point back to a latitude and longitude for your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (completely overseen it - sry for the late response). The problem is that I encountered enough situations where there were only one or two POIs in one district. And then I run in the exact same problem I described above: I'm far aside from the center and the POIs are not enough to tell me even roughly the size of that district. So yes, it's a feature - that I don't need. And it seems that OSM is lacking the kind of feature I'm searching for: Getting the boundaries of a district (or whatever).